# Prove why a closed, continuous bijective map is a homeomorphism.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity, continuous-homomorphisms

Prove why a closed, continuous bijective map is a homeomorphism.
I'm trying to see if $f^{-1}$ is continuous but nothing happens.

Comment: Note that $f(A) = (f^{-1})^{-1} (A)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Theorem.** A map $f$ from a metric space $X$ to a metric space $X'$ is continuous iff for every $C$ closed in $X'$ the set $f^{(-1)}(C)$ is closed in $X$.

Can you see now?